# Read in next line from file each call

Tags: bash, scripting, parameter-passing

I have a bash script

```
for ((i=0; i < 2500; i++)); do
    ./program.bin < in >> out
done
```

I want to read from the next line every time I call this. For example this is my in file

```
1024 2048 3096

1045 8754 5412

5648 5457 5646

EOF
```

So the first time through the loop the program gets 1024 2048 3096 as the inputs. The second time through it gets 1045 8754 5412 and so on. I have a feeling the way I have it set up now it continually reads in only the first line. How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
while IFS= read -r line
do
    ./program.bin <<<"$line" >> out
done < in
```

This will read the `in` file line by line, and for each line call `./program.bin`, provide the value read (found inside variable `line`) and supply  it on standard input to the program.

Of course, you could have the program itself be able to handle multi-line input if you are coding this program.